# Shell script : Reading yml with dynamic property key

Tags: shell-script, yaml

Help taken to read the yml(parser code) : https://gist.github.com/pkuczynski/8665367

My YML file is:

```
marketVal:
  envVal:
    hostVal: ipValue
```

And in .sh file I am reading it as

```
market $1
env $2
parse_yaml() {
  local prefix=$2
  local s='[[:space:]]*' w='[a-zA-Z0-9_]*' fs=$(echo @|tr @ '\034')
  sed -ne "s|^\($s\)\($w\)$s:$s\"\(.*\)\"$s\$|\1$fs\2$fs\3|p" \
    -e "s|^\($s\)\($w\)$s:$s\(.*\)$s\$|\1$fs\2$fs\3|p"  $1 |
  awk -F$fs '{
  indent = length($1)/2;
  vname[indent] = $2;
  for (i in vname) {if (i > indent) {delete vname[i]}}
    if (length($3) > 0) {
     vn=""; for (i=0; i<indent; i++) {vn=(vn)(vname[i])("_")}
     printf("%s%s%s=\"%s\"\n", "'$prefix'",vn, $2, $3);
    }
  }'
}

eval $(parse_yaml hostList.yml "config_")

#Here my property key is "config_marketValue_envValue_hostVal"
# so the value of "config_marketValue_envValue_hostVal" is properly coming as "ipValue"
echo ${config_marketValue_envValue_hostVal}
#As I can not hard code the marketVal etc so the key will be like
# "config_${market}_${env}_hostVal"
```

Now if I am doing something like this in script:

```
key="config_${market}_${env}_hostVal"
echo ${key}
ip_value=${key}
echo ${ip_value}
```

It is printing.
    `config_${market}_${env}_hostVal
    *nothing get printed for echo ${ip_value}*`
Whereas the expected output is:

```
config_marketValue_envValue_hostVal
ipValue
```

Can anyone suggest what to do here to read this value, I am very new to shell scripting, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have whitespaces around `=`? They're not allowed in shell.

Comment: Vicky, please [edit] your question and explain what "is not working" means. Do you get an error message? Does it print the wrong value? What happens? Also, that script is very hard to read. Please show us your actual input file and explain what you are expecting your script to do.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk, No whitespace is not there

Comment: You would probably want to use a command line YAML parser. There are (unfortunately) a few of these called `yq` (unfortunately, since the share the same name). One of them might well serve you better than trying to parse this quite complex document standard yourself.

Comment: @terdon, question edited.

Comment: @Kusalananda, could you please share me any example for `yq`, This will help me a lot as I am totally new to this world.

Comment: If you don't have whitespace around the `=` in your script, why do you have it in your question? Please make sure your question accurately represents what you're doing, otherwise we will waste your time and ours giving you wrong solutions.

Comment: @terdon The `=` with whitespace around it is a piece of `awk` code, as far as I can see.

Comment: @terdon, I had to re-write it here as I can not copy and paste the whole code and changed some names and values here, so might be because of that whatspace was introduced. I have corrected the question now.

Comment: parser code taken from : https://gist.github.com/pkuczynski/8665367